# search quadruples in matrix efficiently

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity

I have a matrix of different numbers and I need an efficient algorithm to find all quadruples (four entries where each two are at the same row and each two at the same column),  where all four numbers are positive. For example:

- 1 2 0 0
- 1 1 0 0
- 0 0 1 1

Here we have one quadruple like this

- 1 2
- 1 1

It is easy to find a non-efficient solution but I need something efficient. I would be really grateful for any idea!

Comment: Do you need to list them all or just count them?

Comment: Unless the matrix has any specific properties there isn't much you could do apart from searching the entire matrix, which will be `O(N)` with `N` being the number of elements in the matrix. Best you could do would be sparse matrices in case all matrices contains as many 0s as the one in the question.

Comment: I need to list them.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are non-sparse matrices, I think that the best you can do is to take the bit-wise product of row pairs, where you use the "truthiness" of each element.  I'll alter your example a little:

```
1 2 0 1
1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1
```

The three products will be

```
1*2 T T F F
1*3 T F T F
2*3 F T F F
```

If you have an N*M matrix, where M is within the linear processing capability of your hardware's matrix instructions, then this is a quick N^2 algorithm.

Now, any result with at least two `T` values indicates a quad; you can generate all the coordinates in K^2 time, where K is the quantity of `T`s in the line.

Unfortunately, a dense array will give a nasty N^2 M^2 result.  However, it's tractable, maintainable, and I think it works well for semi-sparse applications.